# In the `cowboy_req` module, how does one set the 'length' and 'period' values in app config?

Tags: erlang, elixir, cowboy

I'm experience a HTTP 413 error with the message `payload_too_large` that is bubbling up from Cowboy.  It appears that my HTTP client is uploading a body that is longer than the default of `64K`, and I haven't yet figured out how to increase that value.

Answer (score 1):

The functions `cowboy_req:read_body` and `cowboy_req:read_urlencoded_body` have variants with two arguments, the second argument being a map of options. You can specify max size  there as `length`:

```
cowboy_req:read_urlencoded_body(Req, #{length => 100000})
```

For more details see [Cowboy documentation](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.8/manual/cowboy_req.read_urlencoded_body/).